# How to read From Text Files line by line - multiple choice Quiz

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hi i really need some help with this, I need to make a multiple choice question program that reads the questions and answers from 2 different text files (notepad files)
but when I try I cant seem to get it working. i have tried loops but that didn't work then I tried arrays but that didn't meet the requirements of reading form a text file

So I come to you all I need help is with reading a text file line by tine and then updating it when a new question needs to be given

I cannot 1 read the line by line (questions.txt) and i need to have match the question which are in answers.txt then i need to update it when next question is clicked

VB.Net

Program i need to create must do the following

- Questions and answers should be loaded from a file called questions.txt and answers.txt respectively

-Questions should also appear in random order, every time program is executed

-update form for next question

-keep track on how many questions are correct

Any resources or tutorials on any of the above would be muchly appreciated

Comment: Your title is not appropriate please change it

Comment: where does the problem lie? Can you read the text file? Are you having a problem displaying the questions?  Can you red anything from the text file? just not all the questions? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Right, I need to randomly grab a line from a file called Questions.txt "The Question" and then if the user selects thee right answer for the question Answers.txt then they get a point, when they click next i need the question updated and the answers updated aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total edits: 198305769 lol. Cleaned up the answer, and this should get you nearly complete. Cheers.

Declare a global variable (integer); that's where you'll assign the amount of questions the user has answered:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim keepScore As Integer = 0
```

Not the neatest, but it appends each line from a selected text file into an array and then you can iterate through it.

```
   Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.ShowDialog()
    Dim xstr = ofd.FileName

    Dim questions() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName)
    Dim answers() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName)

    Dim sw As New StringBuilder

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do Until i = questions.Count()
        sw.AppendLine(Trim(questions(i)))
           MsgBox(questions(i)) 'Only added this so you can see the lines
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Do Until i = answers.Count()
        sw.AppendLine(Trim(answers(i)))
           MsgBox(answers(i)) 'Only added this so you can see the lines
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

Add onto the end of this function an if statement:

```
If CorrectAnswer.Checked = True 'Assuming you are using a RadioButton Group, or CheckBox
   keepScore = keepScore + 1
End If
```

Here is a quick number randomiser, assuming you have 20 questions (change the 20 accordingly to whatever amount of questions you have):

```
    Randomize()
    Dim i As Integer = CInt(Int(20 * Rnd() + 1))
    MsgBox(i)
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Cheers ill start working with it

Comment: Clearing this up a bit, I've realised I've made an error in this. Written it up off the top of my head, so bear with me.

Comment: Quickly built now, iterates line by line in the MsgBox for you. Just remove the MsgBox line, and it can read any line of the questions. If you want it random, you could probably do some Math.Random on the 'i' variable and then it would match the lines in both documents. Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, i do have 20 questions

Comment: fixed the other one but it now says that sw.AppendLine(Trim(answers(i))) is out of bounds, and its not the same problem

Comment: Replace Do Until i = answers.Count() with Do Until i = answers.Count() - 1. Same with the questions Do loop.